# Add a character to each line

Tags: javascript

I have the text in this format

```
 Man like dog.
 Man like to drink.
 Man is the king
```

I want to add a character say ???? to each line in the above text so that the output can look like:

```
 ????Man like dog.
 ????Man like to drink.
 ????Man is the king
```

Can you help me how to do that?

Comment: And how these texts are placed in html?

Comment: Need a little more detail about what this text is. Are these lines in a javascript array? Are they in separate html elements in a web page? All in one HTML element?

Comment: Is it a single string with newline characters or separate strings for each line?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with regular expresion (`.replace(/^/gm, '????')`):

```
> str = "Man like dog.\nMan like to drink\nMan is the king."
'Man like dog.\nMan like to drink\nMan is the king.'
> str = str.replace(/^/gm, '????')
'????Man like dog.\n????Man like to drink\n????Man is the king.'
> console.log(str)
????Man like dog.
????Man like to drink
????Man is the king.
```

Answer (score 2):

Storing the text in an array you can modify each element of the array like this

```
var text = ['Man like dog.', 'Man like to drink.', 'Man is the king.'];

console.log(text.join('\n'));

text = text.map(function(element){ return '????' + element;});

console.log(text.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have an input with the string (having newline separators) which you want to process

```
var array = input.split(/\n/);

var newArray = [];
array.forEach( function(element){

   newArray.push( "????" + element );

} );
console.log( newArray );
```